# How to run Selenium dotnet test in headless mode from command line?

Tags: .net, selenium, testing, cicd, testautomationfx

I am running selenium test written in DotNet from command line using the following command

```
dotnet test myprojectName.csproj
```

It works fine without any problem. How can I run the same tests in headless mode using command line?

Comment: Modify your test to accept an additional argument as `headless` and add the headless property while initializing Chrome. Use the command `dotnet test myprojectName.csproj headless`

Comment: Already have headless property in chrome initializing. This dotnet test myprojectName.csproj headless is not working for me.